# What is the most common approach for designing large scale server programs?

Tags: scalability, server-side

Ok I know this is pretty broad, but let me narrow it down a bit. I've done a little bit of client-server programming but nothing that would need to handle more than just a couple clients at a time. So I was wondering design-wise what the most mainstream approach to these servers is. And if people could reference either tutorials, books, or ebooks.
Haha ok. didn't really narrow it down. I guess what I'm looking for is a simple but literal example of how the server side program is setup. 
The way I see it: client sends command: server receives command and puts into queue, server has either a single dedicated thread or a thread pool that constantly polls this queue, then sends the appropriate response back to the client. Is non-blocking I/O often used?
I suppose just tutorials, time and practice are really what I need.

*EDIT: Thanks for your responses! Here is a little more of what I'm trying to do I suppose.
This is mainly for the purpose of learning so I'd rather steer away from use of frameworks or libraries as much as I can. Take for example this somewhat made up idea:
There is a client program it does some function and constantly streams the output to a server(there can be many of these clients), the server then creates statistics and stores most of the data. And lets say there is an admin client that can log into the server and if any clients are streaming data to the server it in turn would stream that data to each of the admin clients connected.
This is how I envision the server program logic:
The server would have 3 Threads for managing incoming connections(one for each port listening on) then spawning a thread to manage each connection:
1)ClientConnection which would basically just receive output, which we'll just say is text
2)AdminConnection which would be for sending commands between server and admin client
3)AdminDataConnection which would basically be for streaming client output to the admin client

When data comes in from a client to the server the server parses what is relevant and puts that data in a queue lets say adminDataQueue. In turn there is a Thread that watches this queue and every 200ms(or whatever) would check the queue to see if there is data, if there is, then cycle through the AdminDataConnections and send it to each.

Now for the AdminConnection, this would be for any commands or direct requests of data. So you could request for statistics, the server-side would receive the command for statistics then send a command saying incoming statistics, then immediately after that send a statistics object or data.

As for the AdminDataConnection, it is just the output from the clients with maybe a few simple commands intertwined.

Aside from the bandwidth concerns of the logical problem of all the client data being funneled together to each of the admin clients. What sort of problems would arise from this design due to scaling issues(again neglecting bandwidth between clients and server; and admin clients and server.

Comment: Could you write up a user story to better narrow it down. It sounds like you are not talking about a web application, but where you are writing the server yourself.

Comment: Just like chainsaw is not necessary better than a Hacksaw?  Do you have idea of the nature of the data (is it more like bank transaction that you can lose data, or more like game transaction that you don't care much),  throughput rate, response time, etc.

Perhaps, the best detail is to give us your brief specific use case.

Comment: I could point you at my book, but that would be a totally shameless plug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of basic approaches to doing this.

- Worker threads or processes.  Apache does this in most of its multiprocessing modes.  In some versions of this, a thread or process is spawned for each request when the request arrives; in other versions, there's a pool of waiting threads which are assigned work as it arrives (avoiding the fork/thread create overhead when the request arrives).
- Asynchronous (non-blocking) I/O and an event loop.  This is basically using the UNIX `select` call (although both FreeBSD and Linux provide more optimized alternatives such as `kqueue`).  [lighttpd](http://lighttpd.net) uses this approach and is able to achieve very high scalability, but any in-server computation blocks all other requests.  Concurrent dynamic request handling is passed on to separate processes (via CGI) or waiting processes (via FastCGI or its equivalent).

I don't have any particular references handy to point you to, but if you look at the web sites for open source projects using the different approaches for information on their design wouldn't be a bad start.

In my experience, building a worker thread/process setup is easier when working from the ground up.  If you have a good asynchronous framework that integrates fully with your other communications tasks (such as database queries), however, it can be very powerful and frees you from some (but not all) thread locking concerns.  If you're working in Python, [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) is one such framework.  I've also been using [Lwt](http://ocsigen.org) for OCaml lately with good success.